# How to specify a single property/field for a message in Java POJO (Text, Image, Pdf, Doc etc.)?

Tags: java, spring, pojo

I have a Java Spring entity named Message:

```
public class Message {

private String from;
private String to;
private ? message;

}
```

The whole message object is supposed to be stored in MySQL after the create API call and validations.

The issue here is that message field can either be a text/doc/pdf/png etc. So what should the data type of message field be in order to achieve this scenario? I have thought about using byte[] and was wondering if there is any other approach available.

Comment: What is the type of the message column in the MySql table you fetch?

Comment: Usually you don't store file into MySQL directly. Instead, you could store the file system path or URL in to the message Column.

Comment: @vahdet I was counting on the table being automatically created when I created the first message. If I had to create the table manually, I would probably go with BLOB or LBLOB

Comment: @Top.Deck I get your point. However, storing the message in database is not my primary concern. What I'm looking for is a way to specify a common field for any type of incoming message either be it a text or a datafile in such a way that my API does not generate 400 (Bad Request) at the time of entity mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The **byte[]** approach that you mentioned is the correct one, because you're saving a file and it should match a BLOB or LBLOB

However, as you might know, it is not recommended to save a file directly on the database, the better approach is to save the path to the file.